# denote vs indicate

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I am writing a sentence, and are unsure to choose between denote and indicate:

> In old Chinese texts, some numbers are used symbolically rather than scientifically. For example, the expression *qian jin* often **indicates/denote** merely a large amount of wealth and not exactly one thousand units of gold.

As a background knowledge, *qian* literally means thousand and *jin* means gold.

Google defines denote with "be a sign of; indicate". Is there any difference in this context?

Thanks.

Comment: denote versus connote. indicate just means to show. Have you looked up denote? Please do.

Comment: @Lambie https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denote here shows some definitions of denote. I think the first one "to serve as an indication of" is what I will apply in my sentence. But still, "indication" is derived from "indicate". My question is, do they mean or imply anything different for native speakers? I just cannot tell the difference. Maybe they are fully interchangeable here?

Comment: Alternatively you could say "often **means** merely..."

Comment: Please see the following link: denotation versus connotation. Indicate is just to show something. To denote something is different. If you denote something, you provide its direct meaning, not its suggested meaning.

Comment: Thank you @Lambie. I guess I have got your point. We use denote to say a direct, straightforward meaning, while use indicate to say a relatively more secondary, suggestive meaning. Now I have a further question. I have searched the difference between "indicate" and "imply" before. It's said that "indicate" is to strongly suggest, "imply" is to hint. So can I say that generally "denote > indicate > imply" by the degree of straightforwardness.

Comment: @PeterJennings Thank you!

Comment: No, we use **denote** to say the literal meaning and **connote** to mean non-literal  meanings. Both the word denote and connote **indicate** something. Denote and connote are standard terms to discuss meanings. The word indicate is not. The contrast is between denote/connote and not denote/indicate. I hope it's c;lear now.

Comment: Thank you @Lambie, This is very clear! So in the sentence in my original post, I think indicate fits better to the context. Because the "qian jin" here is not used in it's literal meaning. Connote also works here. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

In literature, poetry etc. the word denote refer to the basic meaning of a term whereas connote refers to all other meanings.

For example:

"Look at that pig". denotation= a farm animal
"Look at that pig". connation=a person who is not nice in some way such as being dirty or nasty'

So: the expression qian jin often indicates/denote merely a large amount of wealth

*indicate* there means *shows* (that a person has) a large amount of wealth
Or
its literal meaning (denotation) is a large amount of wealth

Please note: This was probably translated as normally we'd say: great wealth and not a large amount of wealth

Comment: Thanks again for this further explanation. : )